# What does this mean? var _ = this, dataSettings, responsiveSettings, breakpoint;

Tags: javascript

Anyone could explain this?

```
 var _ = this, dataSettings, responsiveSettings, breakpoint;
```

I saw this in the slick slider source at line 40 in version 1.4.1

Comment: It declares 4 variable, `_` which gets `this` as its value, `dataSettings`, `responsiveSettings` and `breakpoint`.

Comment: Its a dirty type of declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a variable declaration.

It means, in short:

```
var _ = this;
var dataSettings;
var responsiveSettings;
var breakpoint;
```

The variables that have no value assigned will still be available in your scope and will *not* throw errors when used.

See the difference between these 3 examples:

**Example 1:**

```
var foo = 'abcdefg'; // Declared with value
if(foo){
    alert('Works');
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
var foo; //is declared without value, aka undefined, is falsy
if(foo){
    alert('This does not get called');
}else{
    alert('This gets called');
}
```

**Example 3:**

```
// No declaration
if(foo){ // This will throw an error and your script stops executing.
    alert('This does not get called');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `_` is assigned the value of `this`. And the rest are just declared but not assigned